# I don't understand this Boolean in while loop

Tags: java

I don't understand how the following boolean works....

```
    int searchedValue = 100;  int pos = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (pos < values.length && !found)
    {
       if (values[pos] == searchedValue) 
       { 
          found = true; 
       }
       else 
       { 
          pos++; 
       }
    }
    if (found) 
    { 
    System.out.println(“Found at position: ” + pos); 
    }
    else { System.out.println(“Not found”); 
    }
```

Here is what I don't understand:

1. boolean found = false, is to set boolean initially to false, right? then in while loop condition && !found: means boolean found not false?? which means while loop will keep looping when found = true??? Totally doesn't make sense to me.
2. Then in the while loop, if value[pos]==searchedValue, set found=true??? But while loop condition !found=false, then it keep looping if value is found, pos++ if value not found??? Again, totally doesn't make sense to me.
3. And of course, as you can see at the end if (found) condition confuse me too, found is set to false, so then if (found) means if (found=false, which means not found), then print out found value????

I mean the whole boolean thing confuses me....can someone explain to me? Please~~~???

Can anyone understand my question? I keep getting answers saying that my question is duplication to somebody else's question and already been answered......I checked out their post, and no! those answers did not answer my questions!!!

The answers on those posts say !found is opposite to found, if found was set to false initially, then !found equals found = true....I understand that! But don't you guys see this is what exactly confuse me!!!

!found is opposite to found initial value, in this code, found = false is initial value, then in while loop condition !found means found = true. which mean while loop only loops if found = true??? why???

and in while loop, if condition found is set to true, then keep looping...why?? if value is found, shouldn't set found=false to jump out of the loop instead??

Then at the end if (found), print, why??? found=false, if (false), print found value just doesn't make sense....

This block of code is in a textbook, the author totally didn't explain it, just said should code like this, and I just couldn't understand why....someone who understand my question please explain it to me please!!!

And how can I take duplicate mark off my question? please do not mark my question duplicate, because ppl just stop answering me. I checked out all the posts ppl marking me as duplication, and the answers did not answer my question....you know what? I'm just going to duplicate my own question to the same site, since some ppl just mark me duplicate blindly, and I did not get my answers because of that.

Comment: Why do you believe conditions test for `== false`? They don't.

Comment: "...which means while loop will keep looping when found = true??? " No, it means when the condition '!found' is true which is only when found is false

Comment: Well, If I know how to code and understand them, then I wouldn't read beginner java textbook and asking seemingly stupid questions here, isn't it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `boolean` can be either `true` or `false`.

`found` is being used as a control flag. It is initially set to `false` as you haven't found anything. It's used in the expression at the head of your `while` loop so that the loop only executes if `found` is `false`, ie. the loop will terminate once you've found something. `found` is set to `true` when a match occurs (within the loop) to make this happen. Once the loop is done, the output is based on the value of `found`.

The `while` loop will continue to execute for as long as the expression

```
pos < values.length && !found
```

is `true`. Given that you are using and (`&&`), both parts of the expression must be `true`.

If we look at `!found` closely, this sub-expression is `true` when `found` is `false`. This is because the `!` operator negates the value of the expression it is applied to. So, if `found` is `false`, `!found` is `true`. Equally, if `found` is `true`, then `!found` is `false`. Hence the loop continues to execute while `found` is `false`.

The printed output also depends on the value of `found`. The `if` statement has an expression much like the `while` loop, ie. what happens depends on whether the expression is `true` or `false`.

In your case, `if (found)` is the simplest of all expressions, ie. is `found` `true` or `false`. You can think of it as `if (found == true)` if that helps. Java's idiom is to omit the `== true`.

Comment: But why while condition is ! found??? ! found means not found, right? Since found = false, found  alone means not found, right? then ! found means not not found, in other words, ! found means found, means found = true......Right? That was what confuse me.....Can you explain it to me???

Comment: @user3390471 I've updated my answer to address the question in your comment.

Comment: Yes, thank you for updating your answers to answer me. And ahhh, that is mega confusing conditioning, if not you explain to me so well, I can never figure that out........And one more question, at the end if condition, `if (found)`, that `found = true or false`, and why and how the condition works??? Please please explain it to me......I'm chewing on this block of code for 3 days already, can't even sleep soundly.......>.<

Comment: @user3390471 I've updated my answer again.

Comment: ahhhh, thank you! as you can see, I'm a very beginner to Java....And have a textbook doesn't explain things........>~>